# Link dentro de uma div com onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma div que ao ser clicada exibe um alert ao usuário, porém dentro dessa div tem também um link que quando for clicado direciona o usuário a uma outra pagina, mais quando eu clico nesse link ele exibe antes o alert que está na div, como eu posso ignorar esse alerta ao clicar no link que está dentro da div?

Segue exemplo;

```css
.lista_endereco {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.lista_endereco:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista_endereco" id="2" onclick="alert('oi');">
    <div style="width: calc(100% - 60px); font-size: 14px">
        <div style="float: left; width: 40px"></div>
        <div style="float: left; width: calc(100% - 40px)">
                    
            <div style="color:#000">Barão de Uchoa, 735</div>
            <div style="padding-top: 6px; color:#777">323 - Nilopoles , RJ - CEP 32113340</div>
            <div style="color:#777">Alves Silva - 21 971137601</div>
            
            <a href="http://uol.com.br">
                <div style="padding-top: 16px; color: #B12528">
                    <span style="padding-right: 14px;">Editar endereço</span>
                </div>
            </a>
                    
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu evento de click é disparado tendo como origem o elemento que é clicado. Então o evento "*sobe*" (`bubbling`) até a raiz do seu documento, sendo capturado por todos os demais elementos ancestrais desse clicado, e se esses elementos tiverem uma função handler para o evento `onclick`, a função será invocada.

Se você não quer que o evento disparado no seu link suba, você pode invocar o método `stopPropagation` nesse evento para interromper sua propagação.

Exemplo:

```css
.lista_endereco {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.lista_endereco:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista_endereco" id="2" onclick="alert('oi');">
    <div style="width: calc(100% - 60px); font-size: 14px">
        <div style="float: left; width: 40px"></div>
        <div style="float: left; width: calc(100% - 40px)">
                    
            <div style="color:#000">Barão de Uchoa, 735</div>
            <div style="padding-top: 6px; color:#777">323 - Nilopoles , RJ - CEP 32113340</div>
            <div style="color:#777">Alves Silva - 21 971137601</div>
            
            <a href="http://uol.com.br" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
                <div style="padding-top: 16px; color: #B12528">
                    <span style="padding-right: 14px;">Editar endereço</span>
                </div>
            </a>
                    
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu para entender perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="lista_endereco" id="2" onclick="alert('oi');">
<div style="width: calc(100% - 60px); font-size: 14px">
    <div style="float: left; width: 40px"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: calc(100% - 40px)">
                
        <div style="color:#000">Barão de Uchoa, 735</div>
        <div style="padding-top: 6px; color:#777">323 - Nilopoles , RJ - CEP 32113340</div>
        <div style="color:#777">Alves Silva - 21 971137601</div>
        
        <a onclick = "link(event)" href="http://uol.com.br">
            <div style="padding-top: 16px; color: #B12528">
                <span style="padding-right: 14px;">Editar endereço</span>
            </div>
        </a>
                
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

```html
<script>
    function link(event) {
        window.location = "http://uol.com.br";
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
</script>
```

eu usei javascript pra colocar um outro onclick e chamar o link por uma função que logo depois de ser clicado desativaria os outros eventos